# Two-step training in neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In the article https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-51269-8 on sleep-stage classification, the author mentions two-step training. Specifically,

"In the pretraining step, the scoring module (Fig. 2) is temporarily replaced with a softmax layer, which plays the same roles as the original scoring module...In the fine-tuning step, the softmax layer is replaced by the original scoring module. Then, the entire system is trained again using the same training dataset..."

***I do not want the actual code***. I just want a code snippet that demonstrates the idea of using two-step training like the one mentioned in the article.  It can be as short as you like, but it must show how two-step training is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Functional API of Keras](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/). It enables you to define your layers separately and assing to a variable. Hence you could connect and disconnect your layers at any time.